# Laravel Eloquent add to table returns null in increment columns

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, sql-insert

here is my table

[image: 1]

my error seems to show that when I am trying to run the insert eloquent, the both my id columns
give out a null value, this the issue:

> SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "id" of relation "hms_bbr_category" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (null, null, Insert 1, Insert Desc, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null). (SQL: insert into "hms_bbr_category" ("category_name", "category_description") values (Insert 1, Insert Desc) returning "id")

**Model:** HmsBbrCategory

```
class HmsBbrCategory extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hms_bbr_category';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('/bbr-category-configuration', function(){
    $addCategory = new App\Models\HmsBbrCategory;
    $addCategory->category_name='Insert 1';
    $addCategory->category_description='Insert Desc';
    $addCategory->save();
});
```

Note that I am strting it out simple at first, where the insert triggers when a route link is clicked.

I tried manually inserting an increment option, but it still seems to be not working properly.

```
$addCategory = id->id + 1;
$addCategory = category_id->category_id + 1;
```

Thanks for any help, feel free to tell me to elaborate if the question still needs clarification

**Update**

- just to note, I did not create this with migration, this table as given to me as it is, no changes are allowed.
- updated my insert with columns containing "NOT NULL" but im getting another error:

  ```
  $addCategory = new App\Models\HmsBbrCategory;
  $addCategory = id->id + 1;
  $addCategory = category_id->category_id + 1;
  $addCategory->category_name='Insert 1';
  $addCategory->category_description='Insert Desc';
  $addCategory->created_by='Me';
  $addCategory->category_description=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
  $addCategory->save();
  ```

error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)
```

Comment: paste your table full structure

Comment: added, hope that helps

Comment: How did you create the table? Using laravel migrations? Did you do it like this? https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#column-method-bigIncrements

Comment: the table was given to me, i has already been created

Comment: `$addCategory = id->id + 1;` is invalid syntax... It should be `$addCategory->id = $addCategory->id + 1;`, although that won't work, as `$addCategory->id` would be `null` by default... Why are you trying to set `id` manually like that; it should be an auto-incrementing primary key. `$addCategory = category_id->category_id + 1;` is also invalid. Please use proper PHP stynax.

Comment: whats the proper syntax for getting the highest value + 1?

Answer (score 0):

per your table structure , these columns can't be null and have no default value  :

- category_id
- created_by
- created_datetime

so when you insert / update , these columns can't stay null.

so in your code , you are not providing any of those values.

also "id->id + 1" is wrong , because you don''t have a variable called id , and even if you had ,  not  sure what does "id + 1" supposed to give your PK in table.

however id has a default value and seems like it gets nextval() , so you are good there.

but for category_id , you need to pass an integer id , if you want to get the last category_id in the table and add 1 as a new one , this is not how you can do it.

Comment: tried updating with these, added the columns with not null, but im getting another error, i updated my question.

Comment: what will the code look like if i want to get the highest int value + 1?

Comment: @ButtonPress you have to fetch max(category_id) from table , using sql , then add add up 1. however this is a bad approach , best approach is to set identity for the columns

Comment: so how do i set identity?

Comment: @ButtonPress , it depends on your dbms  , but GIYF ;)

Comment: I would not be asking if i can find it on google easily, thats why im requesting for advice for me to learn here.